# Ignorar linhas PERL

Tags: perl

Fiz um script que lê as linhas de um arquivo, porém agora preciso ignorar as 3 primeiras linhas e a última, retornando apenas o que está no meio.

Segue abaixo um modelo do arquivo de texto e do script.

texto.txt:

```
H000000000000000000dsadsadsadsa0sad0sa0da0sd0sad0asd0asd0sa0s
H000000000000000000dsadsadsadsa0sad0sa0da0sd0sad0asd0asd0sa0s
H000000000000000000dsadsadsadsa0sad0sa0da0sd0sad0asd0asd0sa0s

FFFFFFFFF TESTE12 N TESTE12
FFFFFFFFF TESTE13 N TESTE13
FFFFFFFFF TESTE14 N TESTE14
FFFFFFFFF TESTE15 N TESTE15

T9999999999999999999esksddjsadsdk
```

script.pl:

```perl
# ! /usr /bin /perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'data.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename);

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  print "$row\n";
}
print "Final\n";
```

Se alguém puder dar uma direção, agradeço pois estou olhando alguns materiais na internet mais ainda assim estou com dificuldades...

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo o código pronto. Deixei ele comentado da forma como entendi, caso tenha algo errado peço desculpas, mais o código esta funcionando perfeitamente.
OBS: O código elimina o cabeçalho e rodapé e, tambem separa o conteúdo restante.Após a leitura ele gera um arquivo de saida com as informações...

```
        #!/usr/bin/perl 
        use strict; 
        use warnings;

        my $fh; 
        my $fhout; 
        my $filename = 'data.txt';  # Entrada do arquivo 
        if (open($fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename)) { # Abre o arquivo    
          open($fhout, ">:encoding(ASCII)", 'saida.txt');  # Arquivo de saída   
          while (my $row = <$fh>) {  # Enquanto retornar algo faça...
             next if ($row =~/^[HT]/); # Desconsidera linhas que comecem com H e T
             $row =~ s/\s+$//;
       #     my ($funcional, $login, $nome) = ($row =~ /^([0-9]{9}) ([^\s]+) N (.+)$/); 
       # Caso a funcional receba um valor numérico de 9 digitos, faz a leitura e separação
             my ($funcional, $login, $nome) = ($row =~ /^(F{9}) ([^\s]+) N (.+)$/); # Faz a leitura e separação
             print "$row\n";
             print $fhout "funcional $funcional\n";
             print $fhout "login $login\n";
             print $fhout "nome $nome\n";   } } print "Fim!\n";
       #     close ($fh);       # Fecha o arquivo de entrada
       #     close ($fhout);    # Fecha o arquivo de saida
```